# Visual Studio - Javascript - Writing to the Output Window

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, window

I am using VS2010 Express. I am wrting a javascript function.

I want to write a message to the output folder so I can see what was accessed during the program.

eg

```
function Myfunction() {
    console.write("point a has been reached");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are debugging a web page, put the following in the HEAD section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

And then:

```
Debug.writeln("hello");
```

will output to the immediate window. If you are using Visual Studio to debug a windows scripting javascript via cscript, then you should be able to use Debug.writeln without any additional code.